# Extremely large confidence intervals- what to do?

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval

I ran a logistic regression for my dissertation and one of my variables came out with extremely large confidence intervals (e.g., CI95 .41 to 560.45) while all my other independent variables had very normal CIs. The variable I have large CIs with was log transformed. I transformed some of my other IVs and had no problem. My variable with large CIs was non-significant.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You have an excellent answer, but bear in mind that your confidence interval might be quite reasonable given the units & context.

Answer (score 5):

How did you compute your intervals?

A common method estimates the standard error then adds and subtracts a multiple of the s.e. to the coefficient.  This is called the Wald method and in logistic regression can suffer from what is called the Hauk-Donner effect where because of the shape of the binomial likelihood far from the maximum, the standard error is grossly over estimated and the confidence intervals are way too wide.

If you can create confidence intervals based on the likelihood ratio test instead of the Wald test, then you don't need to worry about this effect.  The LR approach usually uses profiling which is more computationally intensive, but reasonable with modern computers.

So the first step is to figure out how your software computed the intervals and see if you can compute new LR based intervals.  That may solve your problem, and if not, it will at least give some more insight.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I simply used SPSS and clicked the box for it to provide the CIs. Do you know of any links/videos that explains the method you are suggesting?

Comment: @user209517, not in SPSS, I have not used it for years.  It is pretty straight forward in R.